# Moving CSS content onto a border

Tags: html, css

Right, I ran into a bit of a problem and not to sure if this can be solved another way.

I need to move the `content: "F";` and center it onto the border I have in the top left corner. Now is this possible without creating another element?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="userBoxF"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.userBoxF {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.userBoxF:after {
    content: "F";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 40px solid #F385FF;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

The only way I can think to do it is to create the corner as a completely separate element so I can put the text "F" into a `span` (or something) and move it that way.

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/qGGSj/1)

**Note:** Nothing here will change size, width and height for both the box and corner will always be the same.

---

Here is what I want, using the solution i found but would rather not use.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="userBoxF">
    <div class="corner"><span>F</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.userBoxF {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.userBoxF .corner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 40px solid #F385FF;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.userBoxF .corner span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: -20px;
}
```

Here is a demo of the solution I came up with but I would rather not create anymore elements.

[My Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/qGGSj/2/)

Comment: Using `:after` for the "F" and `:before` for the border isn't an option?

Comment: @jdo Anything that is shorter then my solution is a potential option. But was mainly looking for a way to move the text without creating any new `HTML`.

Comment: There won't be any new elements on the page. Both `:after` and `:before` are pseudo-elements. All that @jdo proposed, is to separate `content: "F";` to the `:before` CSS rule. Might also need to set proper `z-index` (since both will have position `absolute`.

Comment: @Devtrix.net Ah yeah I miss read it, thanks for clearing that up for me! Yeah that is a way I would be willing to accept. If no one wants to write it up I can do it myself.

Comment: Hmmm...arguably the "F" is actual content as it's not a styling option...it actually denotes something. So I would prefer a positioned span for this rather than a pseudo-element.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/qGGSj/4/

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, so you think a `span` here is the better option? Hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:before` wit `:after` together.

I removed the `span`:

```
<div class="userBoxF">
</div>
```

And changed the CSS blocks to this:

```
.userBoxF:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 40px solid #F385FF;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    content: "";
}

.userBoxF:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 14px;
    content: "F";
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

[And here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGGSj/5/)

### **EDIT:** Here's an added bonus!

You can jack the "F" from the class, if you want it to be more versatile, if you use CSS's `attr` inside `content`. Example:

```
<div class="userBox" data-l="F">
</div>
```

And:

```
.userBox:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 14px;
    content: "" attr(data-l);
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

[And another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGGSj/8/)

Comment: IE8+, all other browsers way long ago, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr), which is same as `:after` support as far as IE is concerned. `attr` is unsupported in all browsers if you're using it on places other than `content`, though

Answer (score 1):

Simply use another `:psuedo`:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/qGGSj/6/)

```
.userBoxF {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.userBoxF:before,.userBoxF:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;   
}
.userBoxF:before {
    content:"";
    border: 40px solid #F385FF;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.userBoxF:after {
    content:attr(data-l);
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the "F" is actual content as it's not a styling option...it actually denotes something and, perhaps should be read by a screenreader (for instance) then a span with a gradient (TL - BR) mightbe more appropriate.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/qGGSj/14/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="userBoxF">
    <span class="section-letter">F</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.userBoxF {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.section-letter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:2em;
    height:2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding:0.25em 0 0 0.25em;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, pink 0%, pink 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a single pseudo, you can use a gradient as background : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qGGSj/15/)**

```
.userBoxF {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.userBoxF:after {
    content:"F";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-indent:20px;
    line-height:60px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #F385FF 51%, transparent 49%);
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

background-image as gradient can be just an image like in old days :

[image: demo image]  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qGGSj/16/)**:

Comment: yep not easy, see that gradient can be a background image set in center for better compatibiliti :)

Comment: Gradients are not as supported though, I think. IE9 still struggles with some types

Comment: @ChenAsraf my previous comment is about this actually :)